# libreoffice basic hide/delete some legend entries - possible?

Tags: libreoffice

I search for a way to manipulate the legend entries of a chart via a basic macro.

Manually this can be done by clicking the data line in a line diagram and activate "Hide legend entry" under the Options tab.

Could you present a code line therefore?

We can get the legend by

```
oChart = ThisComponent.getSheets().getByIndex(0).getCharts().getByIndex(0)
oDiagram = oChart.getEmbeddedObject().getFirstDiagram()
oLegend = oDiagram.Legend
```

and we can hide or show the whole legend by

```
rem true=1, false=0
oLegend.show = 1
```

Assume we have a chart with 3 data lines.
How can we hide the legend of the second only?

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Yes, you are right - repeated property names can be confusing. In this case, the "Legend" you got from the `.getFirstDiagram()` is just the legend display, a rectangle with colored marks and labels. If you start to explore the object Chart, then the word "Legend" will meet in different places and will mean different things.*

Let's think: if you use the **series property** to turn an element on and off, then you need to look for the desired element in the **series**, right?

```
  oCoordinateSystems = oFirstDiagram.getCoordinateSystems()
  oXCoordinateSystem = oCoordinateSystems(0) ` first and only coordinate system
  
  oChartTypes = oXCoordinateSystem.getChartTypes()
  oXChartType = oChartTypes(0) ` first and only ChartType
  oDataSeries = oXChartType.getDataSeries()
  
  oXDataSeries = oDataSeries(1)  ' As you want - second Series
  oXDataSeries.ShowLegendEntry = False ' Set "not show in Legend"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I manipulated the dataseries for linewidth and colors and tried a lot for the legend thing but I saw nowhere ShowLegendEntry. Even chatgpt was a catastrophe ;) I was searching within the api docs too. So, I'm really glad you answered. I test it tomorrow and will then accept your answer.